# Annotate 2 points on map using addresses inside labels. - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dictionary, annotate

[image]

I would like to drop a pin on the map showing the location of each address.  The labels are pre-filled with data, so I am assuming the annotation code will need to go in the `viewDidLoad`.

To avoid any confusion and to help clarify a correct answer, the labels are named `lblLeftAddress` and `lblRightAddress`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reapeat the same process for lblRightAddress also.

```
 // NSString *location = lblLeftAddress.text; I hust checked with your address it worked.
 NSString *location = @"296 Broadway Blvd Santa Monica CA 90016";
        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:location
                     completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                         if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                             CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                             MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];

                             MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
                             region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                             region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;

                             [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                             [self.mapView addAnnotation:placemark];
                         }
                     }
         ];
```

[image: output]

Comment: I placed this code in the viewDidLoad, but am still getting a blank map with no annotations.  Should it be placed elsewhere?

Comment: give breakpoint and check whether you are getting some value in placemark or not.

Comment: I checked with this ( NSString *location = @"296 Broadway Blvd Santa Monica CA 90016";) Its working .. I am attaching aScreen shots.

Comment: Awesome! Good to know that it works.  I'm going to try it right now.  I appreciate the help Nilesh :)

Comment: Now, how can I draw a poly line between the two place mark annotations?  THANK YOU!

Comment: https://iostpoint.wordpress.com/2016/08/14/draw-route-between-two-places-and-finding-distance-between-them-in-mkmapview/

Answer (score 0):

Just change the coordinates here in source and destination.

```
#pragma mark - Show Route Direction

-(void)loadRoute
{
    MKPlacemark *source = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(34.0207504,-118.69193) addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];

    MKMapItem *srcMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:source];
    [srcMapItem setName:@""];

    MKPlacemark *destination = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.757815,-122.5076406) addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];

    MKMapItem *distMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:destination];
    [distMapItem setName:@""];

    MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc]init];
    [request setSource:srcMapItem];
    [request setDestination:distMapItem];
    [request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile];

    MKDirections *direction = [[MKDirections alloc]initWithRequest:request];

    [direction calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"response = %@",response);
        NSArray *arrRoutes = [response routes];
        [arrRoutes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            MKRoute *rout = obj;

            MKPolyline *line = [rout polyline];
            [self.mapView addOverlay:line];
            NSLog(@"Rout Name : %@",rout.name);
            NSLog(@"Total Distance (in Meters) :%f",rout.distance);

            NSArray *steps = [rout steps];

            NSLog(@"Total Steps : %lu",(unsigned long)[steps count]);

            [steps enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"Rout Instruction : %@",[obj instructions]);

            }];
        }];
    }];

}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        [renderer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [renderer setLineWidth:3.0];
        return renderer;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

For more reference you can visit this [here](https://iostpoint.wordpress.com/2016/08/14/draw-route-between-two-places-and-finding-distance-between-them-in-mkmapview/)